# I am having a problem downloading the Ubuntu software from the web site?

Tags: downloads

I am currently using Windows Vista Professional. When I go to the Ubuntu web site and start a download of Version 12 I get a DVD error message that the download has not completed. What can I do to obtain the Ubuntu software?I would like to change my O/S to Ubuntu.

Comment: have you tried the alternate downloads page? http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads I've always had the best speeds using torrent downloads (plus you can pause/resume them).

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the alternative methods mentioned in the below link

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads